# Automatically return to input form on @Valid failure

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have the following method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/status", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@Valid StatusForm statusForm, BindingResult result) {    
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "statusForm";
    }
    //do stuff when there are no errors        
        return "dashboard";
}
```

It seems like in a lot of these methods there is a repeating code block:

```
if(result.hasErrors()) {
    return "statusForm";
}
```

Is there a way to avoid having to insert this block and automatically redirect back to where the POST request came from in an event of Validation errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same action can be accessed from multiple pages, so you would have to configure the error view somehow. In struts for example, you have an xml file describing the input jsp for each action. It would probably be possible to create an annotation containing the view id and implement a [AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.html) to handle this logic.

The current way of doiing this in code has one advantage. It allows you to to additional validations in your action method, maybe checking some values in a database or some more complicated business rules, and handling this errors in a uniform way.

Comment: I am coming from Struts and Struts2 hence the reason for my question! I understand the value in additional validation but in numerous simpler cases where the additional validation is not required it would be a good option to have.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller handler method, make sure that the BindingResult argument is immediately after the command argument.